# php scandir for given $q search query

Tags: php, search, scandir

i have search values like "search value" (defined as $q) and .txt files called "search value.txt" in /mydir/ directory. How can i scandir /mydir/ for the search value ($q) and put the found .txt file with php include command  into page? Or is it a better way to put $q value into php file_get_contents php code (i mean put them together like a txt filename like (q$.txt -  searchvalue.txt somehow) and pull the content of the .txt file into page? If yes, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I find your concept is rather questionable - and in PHP, the scan-dir is for it's INI files. What have you tried so far? There is no attempt shown, but it is merely gimme-teh-codez. Sorry, but I'm not stupid enough to do YOUR work. See http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ ...posting your specs does not qualify as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have this directory structure :

```
mydir
  --file1.tx
  --file2.tx
index.php
```

index.php

```
$filepath = glob("mydir/*.txt");//read all txt files in data directory
//print_r($filepath);//debug purpose
$search = 'file1';

// Browse all files and search the $search string in filenames
foreach ($filepath as $filename) {

    // Give us file name only without the extension
    $fileNameOnly = basename($filename, '.txt');

    // Check if a file name only contains exactly our keyword $search
    $isExactMatch = preg_match("/\b".$search."\b/iu", $fileNameOnly);

    if ( $isExactMatch ) {
      // Include the .txt file as result
      require $filename;
    }
}
```

Tested, it does the trick.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply and answer. I have .txt files with different names like some word.txt, other word.txt. I just want to search .txt filenames in /mydir/ directory and if the search query matches the .txt filename, include the .txt file as result. It is a php search landing page with a $q variable. I know it's a little bit tricky what i want to do here.:)

Comment: $search =  $q.txt; putting the search query together with .txt fileextension somehow.:)

Comment: Ok @BizzyFizzy, I've updated my answer based on your needs. Tested it works. Let me know if it's right for you.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your solution @Monnmcjo! I wish you a nice day!